# How to create a ListView with 2 values but displays one of them and the second for other purpose

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-listview

I have two Android activities.

The first one is to display books titles in a ListView. The data comes from a web service and read the book ID

By clicking on an item (its value is the book title) it will go to the second activity to display the book details from other web service but it depending on the book ID.

How can I make the ListView in the first activity displays the title but passing the ID?

Comment: What adapter do you use for listview?

Answer (score 0):

Make a listview with "homemade" items and pass the ID in the constructor and the variables of this item.
Exemple :

```
public class TextBook extends LinearLayout {

private String id;

public TextBook(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, String id) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.id = id;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, this);
}

}
```

Or something like that. And don't forget to retrieve a textview or what ever you use in your layout and put the setters (And of course your adapter.).

Answer (score 0):

use such adapter with your listview and implement onItemClickListener for the listview.get the position from onItemClickListener and send bookId[position] to next activity where you want to display details of the particular book having book id similar to bookId[position].

```
public class MySimpleAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] bookTitle;
    private final Integer[] bookId;


public MySimpleAdapter(Activity context, String[] title,Integer[] id) 
{
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.bookTitle = title;
    this.bookId = id;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return bookTitle.length;
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{


    //inflating
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_inflater,null);


    //binding
        final TextView tvTitle=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);

    tvTitle.setText(bookTitle[position]);


    return convertView;


}
```